# AppleScript Fastest Way to Get Selected Rows From a Large Table?

Tags: applescript, javascript-automation

I have a large table with about 1000 rows. If I try to get selected rows from the table, it takes more than 30 seconds. Is there way to speed up the process? I use JXA.

```
selected = table.rows.whose({selected:true})()
names = ""
for (r in selected) {
    names+=", "+selected[r].uiElements[1].name()
}
console.log(names)
```

Is there a faster way?
Thanks!

Comment: Strange as it sounds, depending on the app you are targeting, it is sometimes faster to just repeat through all the rows, and collect the selected rows into a list.

Comment: Thanks Craig for the suggestion. Unfortunately that was even slower in this situation.

Comment: Your example script is insufficient to analyze.  Please provide complete script, including the application object.  It would also be helpful to know what you plan to do with the selected rows in JXA.

Comment: @JMichaelTX, I revised the question to provide more code, but there isn't much to it really since it's just test script for now.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can just narrow down using specifier without going through each element to get names for them.

```
names = table.rows.whose({selected:true}).uiElements[1].name()
```

This was much faster for my case.

Comment: Should that backtick (`) be there next to the equals sign?

Comment: What would be the applescript counterpart to this JXA?